# How to return "TRUE"/"FALSE" for matches in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` like this:

```
df = data.frame("Gene1" = c("A","B","C","D"),
                "Gene2" = c("B","E","NA","NA"),
                "Gene3" = c("B","D","E","F"))
```

I wanted to transform it into a data frame with `Gene` as the row names and all possible characters as the column names, showing "TRUE" or "FALSE" for matches. Something like this:

```
           A      B      C      D      E      F
Gene1   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
Gene2  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
Gene3  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

I am still learning R so could someone show me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compact option would be `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(df)[-6]!=0  #removed the 6th column as it is NA
#          A    B     C     D     E     F
#Gene1  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#Gene2 FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#Gene3 FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```